# How to not stack cards together in apple wallet?

Tags: passbook, wallet, apple-wallet

How would I issue multiple cards without having them stack together? knowing that these cards are issued dynamically in my system. I can't go through the manual create certificate process each time.

How would that work?

Answer (score 1):

For storecard passes, using different certificates is the only way to prevent grouping. storecard and generic passes with the same passTypeIdentifier will always be grouped together.

For other pass types such as *eventTicket* and *boardingPass* types, we could make use of **groupingIdentifier** key to separate passes with the same passTypeIdentifier into different groups.

[groupingIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/pass?language=_2)
string

> An identifier the system uses to group related boarding passes or
> event tickets. Wallet displays passes with the same
> groupingIdentifier, passTypeIdentifier, and type as a group. Use this
> identifier to group passes that are tightly related, such as boarding
> passes for different connections on the same trip.